# Embedded python on c++. Error occurs when i change debugger

Tags: python, c++, debugging

Hi Im doing Embedded python onto c++.
I installed both anaconda3(x64) and anaconda3(32bit)
My computer has x64 processor, and OS is windows 10.
I just tried simple code below it works at x64 debugger but it doesn't work
at x86 debugger at Visual Studio 2015.

I matched properties or libraries at each debugger.
(i.e. with x86 debugger, I gave anaconda3(32bit) directory for lib or includes.)

c++ code

```
#include <Python.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
Py_Initialize();
PyRun_SimpleString("print ('Hello, World!\')\n");
Py_Finalize();
return 0;
}
```

As i told, it works well with x64 debugger but 
it doesn't work with x86 and it gives [error(click me)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4UQ2.png).
And [this(click me)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kN440.png)is outcome with x64 debugger

I saw the code through the debugger, the problem was at "codecs.c" file.
At the end of the file, there is the phrase with

```
mod = PyImport_ImportModuleNoBlock("encodings");
if (mod == NULL) {
    return -1;
}    
Py_DECREF(mod);
interp->codecs_initialized = 1;
return 0;
```

The variable "mod" doesn't get any of value(it has NULL with x86 debugger).
On the contrary, the variable "mod" has some value with x64 debugger.

I really need to run at x86 debugger cus I have to apply some .py file at
my application that is very complex with x86 debugger.
Is there anyone can give some solution for the issue?

Comment: So encodings are not available, no problem. However, I notice that you have a PyDECREF later in the function, and you skip that. It's probably needed. Consider RIAA

Comment: Thanx for your advice. However, it doesn't work too. I don't think that is critical point for my issue because of x64 debugger case. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution for my issue**

I fixed my issue by installing VS2017.
When I install VS2017 I added python development tools with
additional tool kits: native development tools and python3 (32bit).
May be the issue was about my python3 (32bit) or some c++ development tools.
I'm not that clear about why did my issue occured but I hope this would be helpful for who is suffering from the same issue.
For more questions, I will keep check this text and answer for that.
Tanks.